# Windows 8.1 Shutdown Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a pretty (to what I imagine) simple question/request for help. The only problem is I am not sure how to really have the script set up, so I would very much appreciate any help/suggestions.

**Here's exactly what I am looking for in my batch file:**

- When I execute the batch file, it initiates a shutdown in ~2 hours.

...and that's really it :o)

With that said, leading to my question, is initiating a shutdown from a batch file a 'clean' shutdown? For example, are you calling Windows shutdown, safely saving/closing any currently opening applications, and then shutting down? Or is it forcing the system to not save any work, and shuts off 'unsafe'? I imagine it's the former, although I just want to be sure.

Regards,

Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
shutdown /s /t 7200
```

Save this with a .bat extention and this will shutdown your computer safely just like shuting it down from the desktop

Comment: That's what I imagined it was going to be close to, but thank you very much for confirming it for me, and also answering my other question!

Regards,

Patrick

Comment: I wouldn't name the script `shutdown.bat` (since this would cause an endless loop) and you can add a `/f` to force everything to close like: `shutdown /s /f /t 7200`

Answer (score 2):

Shutting down through the "shutdown" command is perfectly safe.  I've done it many times on my computers and nothing has happened.  So to make this batch file, all you're going to need to do is paste this one line in:

```
shutdown /s /t 7200
```

The /s flag tells Windows to shutdown, and the /t flag tells it to shutdown after a certain amount of time in seconds.  In this case, you want 7,200 seconds, or 2 hours.  Good luck!

EDIT: I see that someone already beat me to answering the question lol

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!

I'd vote yours up considering you went into detail and answered as well, however it appears I cannot until ~15 rep. Sorry, but again, thank you!

Regards,

Patrick